# Angular custom validation - Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: angular

Code is producing the error below and is also calling the `shouldBeUnique` method as soon as the page loads. It shouldn't be called until the field is touched.

It is also unclear why 4 sets of objects are being returned instead of 1.

[full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1UBr.jpg)

---

Console output:

> Angular is running in the development mode. Call `enableProdMode()` to enable the production mode.
>
> (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
>
> (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
>
> (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
>
> (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
>       at client-form.component.ts:52

`ClientFormComponent` class:

```
export class ClientFormComponent {

client: any = {};
emails: any[];

form = new FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl('', 
  null,
  (control: AbstractControl) => this.shouldBeUnique(control)),

password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
confirm: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
firstname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
lastname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
address: new FormControl('', Validators.required),    
phone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
medical: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});

constructor(public clientService: ClientService) { }


async shouldBeUnique(control: AbstractControl) : Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {

  this.clientService.getClientEmails().subscribe(email => {
  this.emails = email;
  console.log(this.emails);  
});

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {                                                          

  if (this.emails.find(e => e.email == control.value))         
      resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
  else 
      resolve({ shouldBeUnique: false });                                
});
```

}

Comment: You don't understand asynchronism. The callback passed to subscribe() is called later, asynchronously, when the client emails are finally available. this.emails.find() is called immediately. So this.emails is undefined when it's called,since the callback has not been called yet. You really need to grok asynchronism and learn more about observables and promises.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to read up on those and resolve the issue